# Calculate RMSE on different time intervals

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to write a function to calculate RMSE on different time intervals.
My dataframe has Datetime stamp and I need to give a choice to calculate on daily, weekly or monthly basis. This is the function I have so far:

```
def rmse(dataframe):
    rmse = np.sqrt( mean_squared_error( dataframe['Actual'], dataframe['Predicted'] ) )
    return 'RMSE: %f' % rmse
dataframe.apply(rmse).reset_index()
```

Comment: One way is to create a column with the time slices that you want to find the RMSE's. Then groupby the dataframe and  apply your RMSE for each group.

Answer (score 0):

If the dataframe looks like this. You need to first create the slices of time that you want to apply the RMSE's on.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': pd.date_range('2020-01-01', freq='D', periods=10), 'actual': np.arange(10)
              , 'predictoni': np.arange(10), 'slice': np.repeat([1,2],5)})
    date    actual  predictoni  slice
0   2020-01-01  0   0   1
1   2020-01-02  1   1   1
2   2020-01-03  2   2   1
3   2020-01-04  3   3   1
4   2020-01-05  4   4   1
5   2020-01-06  5   5   2
6   2020-01-07  6   6   2
7   2020-01-08  7   7   2
8   2020-01-09  8   8   2
9   2020-01-10  9   9   2
```

Then you can apply the function like this

```
g = df.groupby(['slice'])
g.apply(rmse)
```